# Code working on Debug but doesn't work on Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I wrote this small code on Cpp using Qt library to load a pointcloud ressource file and copy it into a temporary directory then load it using the library pcl, here is the code:

```
QResource::registerResource(qstring_path_to_resource_file);
QTemporaryDir temporaryDir("Dir");
QFile::copy(":/point_cloud/pc.pcd", temporaryDir.path() + "/pc.pcd");
pcl::io::loadPCDFile(QString(temporaryDir.path() + "/pc.pcd").toStdString(), *pointcloud);
```

It runs fine when I launch it on debug mode but doesn't work on the release. Apparently, it cannot find the temp file I copy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check your IDE settings for running your program. Especially check the differences between working directory for release and debug.

Comment: Check the return value of copy() and errorString() (using the non -static version of copy())

Comment: Just another question, did you build the library both in debug and release mode?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did check that, it's the same directory

Comment: @Salvo yes I did build for both debug and release

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I didn't understand the "the non -static" part of your comment, when checking the return values of copy() and errorString(), they give : True and UnkownError on debug, but gives : False and "Cannot open :/point_cloud/pc.pcd
for input" . Apparently the copy() isn't working on debug, or the registerResource()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the issue was that the ressource file (.rcc) was not properly created.Try to re-create your .rcc file and check again